# Compiling visual basic script in C# Application

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working on functionality that allows users to write VB scripts and attach them to controls as actions. If user wants to perform something more or something specific he can write it in VB script and attach it, for example, to button (whole application is something like powerpoint presentation but with dynamic data etc).

The problem is i have issue compiling the script in C# project.

Input is at least two files (one main script, and other are additional).

This is first method that prepares references adn calls the compilation method.

```
    public CompilerErrorCollection CompileClient(string fname, string[] VbFiles)
    {
        string currentDir = CurrentWorkingDir();

        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        string[] anames = CompilerHelper.DefaultReferencedAssembliesWpf;
        foreach (string s in anames)
        {
            names.Add(s);
        }

        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(currentDir, "PresentationBase.dll"), true);

        var sFolderPath = currentDir + "\\S";
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "Client.WPF.Common.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "Client.WPF.CommonControls.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "Client.WPF.CommonModels.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "Client.WPF.Presentation.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "Client.WPF.SyncfusionControls.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "ClientAd.WPF.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "ClientCore.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "ClientInfrastructure.dll"), true);
        AddReference(names, Path.Combine(sFolderPath, "ClientWcf.dll", true), 

        string filenamestamp = fname + ".stamp";
        string stampPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, filenamestamp);

        try
        {
            string uid = Funcs.UniqeID(true, 12);
            TextWriter wr2 = File.CreateText(stampPath);
            wr2.WriteLine(uid + " " + DateTime.Now);
            wr2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            / ... / 
        }

        CompilerErrorCollection lcErrors;

        CompilerHelper.Compile(VbFiles, out lcErrors, names, fname);

        return lcErrors;
    }
```

Compile method:

```
    public static Assembly Compile(string[] files, out CompilerErrorCollection errors,
        List<string> referencedAssemblies, string outputAssemblyFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo(files[0]);
            CodeDomProvider provider = null;
            errors = new CompilerErrorCollection();
            bool compileOk = false;

            if (sourceFile.Extension.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == ".VB")
            {
                //provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic");
                provider = new VBCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source file must have a .vb extension");
            }

            if (provider != null)
            {
                CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

                // Generate an executable instead of
                // a class library.
                cp.GenerateExecutable = false;

                // Specify the assembly file name to generate.
                cp.OutputAssembly = outputAssemblyFileName; //exeName;

                // Save the assembly as a physical file.
                cp.GenerateInMemory = true;

                // Set whether to treat all warnings as errors.
                cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;

                cp.WarningLevel = 4;
                cp.TempFiles.KeepFiles = false;
                cp.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

                string[] names = new string[referencedAssemblies.Count];
                int nr = 0;
                foreach (string name in referencedAssemblies)
                {
                    names[nr] = name;
                    nr++;
                }

                cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(names);

                // Invoke compilation of the source file.
                //CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, sourceName);
                CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, files);

                errors = cr.Errors;

                if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Display compilation errors.
                    Debug.WriteLine("Errors building assembly into {0}", cr.PathToAssembly);
                    foreach (CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("  {0}", ce.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Display a successful compilation message.
                    Debug.WriteLine("Source built into {0} successfully.", cr.PathToAssembly);
                }

                // Return the results of the compilation.
                if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return cr.CompiledAssembly;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this are references from system:

```
    public static string[] DefaultReferencedAssembliesWpf =
    {
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "System.dll",
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "System.Core.dll",
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "System.Data.dll",
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll",
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "System.Windows.Forms.dll",
        NetRootFolderx86_En + "PresentationCore.dll",
    };
```

After line with CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, files); i got those errors:

```
error BC30009: Reference required to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' containing the implemented interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1'. Add one to your project.} object {System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError}

error BC30451: 'MessageBox' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.}   object {System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError}

error BC30009: Reference required to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' containing the implemented interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1'. Add one to your project.} object {System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError}
```

After i add reference netstandard i get another error with System.Windows.Browser, then with System.Private.CoreLib.dll and adding those don't help.

Does someone have any experience in compiling in similar way or know what I am missing?

The scripts compiles fine without errors when i create VB Console app Project in visual studio.

Why do I even need netstandard in this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have reinstalled .Net Framework 4.8 and after attaching netstandard.dll from .Net Framework directory everything is fine now.